# Is it possible to create a temporal table in SQL Server 2016 using Entity Framework code-first technique?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, temporal

I have a requirement to create a temporal table using Entity Framework code-first. For that I searched so many links but I didn't find any information from those links. Is it possible to create a temporal tables using Entity Framework code-first technique?

Comment: by using Conext.Database.ExecuteSql I think

Answer (score 3):

Native EF support is still on the [to do list](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4693). For now, I would have EF create it as a normal table, and then in the EF migration, add custom SQL to [convert the table to be temporal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590957.aspx#Adding-versioning-to-non-temporal-tables).

Comment: Is there any way to set up `modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().IsTemporal()`, so that my custom migrations are then generated to the migration routine?